# Percentage distribution across y axis in excel chart

Tags: excel, charts, excel-charts

I have a data in following manner:

[image]

I want a chart which has % distribution across y axis.
That means 38% of A have done 0% of B and 33% of A have done 25% of B. How do I represent this on a chart in excel. I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally understand the question. Does each name have just one row? If so, could you add another column, call it "remaining", which would be (1 - %A minus %B), and then create your stacked bar chart?

Comment: Can you use the drawing tools to mock up what you want the chart to look like? The sample you show is not a fit for your data set.